# prestashop - a way to add options to product sort select, based on features?

Tags: sorting, prestashop

in product-sort.tpl I'd like to add other options based on some features. Is it someway possible? I tried to add things like `<option value="qualit:asc"`, based on url params of the blocklayered module, but it doeasn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of you input ?

Must be "orderby" and "orderway".

Regards